# Can't get infowindow to appear on Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am new to javascript programming and am experimenting with the Google Maps V3 API.

Following Google's examples, I'm able to get a marker added, and have it move to the center everytime the window is updated. However, I wish to add an infowindow when the marker is clicked, and this doesn't seem to be working. I tried adding some other function to test that the marker click event is being triggered. That did work, so I'm lead to believe that something is wrong with the way I've created the infowindow.

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  var bboxstr;

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function(event) {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    myMarker.setPosition(center);
    bboxstr = map.getBounds();
    alert("new center is " + center + " and new bbox is " + bboxstr);
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: bboxstr
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,myMarker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've been testing this by using an HTML file on my desktop (that I created with a text editor). I tried to port the example to jsfiddle but can't seem to get that working either. It'd be great if somebody could help me with that too.. :(

http://jsfiddle.net/himenohogosha/CL6cH/

Update : I was able to get the infowindow to appear with help below. My remaining question is, why is content of the infowindow not updating?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Only change `height:300px` in your style. You can't see the map because it isn't height defined.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CL6cH/1/)**

Comment: I hope I've helped you ;) If you're ok don't forget "upvote" :)
Thks!

Answer (score 0):

You have Google API included two times: as external resource from jsfiddle and via  tag.

Map is not shown because there is no style rules for head, body and width of `map-canvas`.

Function `add-marker` is not defined. Commented out.

Infowindow doesn't show up because `bboxstr` is undefined. Even if you set it in event listener later.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CL6cH/2/).

Comment: Your comments were very helpful in pointing out my errors. Much appreciated!

I'm wondering though, how come `bboxstr` doesn't get updated during the dragend event?

Comment: To be more specific, infowindow content is set to `bboxstr`, and `bboxstr` gets updated during the event trigger. Why doesn't the content of the infowindow get updated as well?

Comment: Because infowindow content does know nothing about `bboxstr` update. If you want to update content in that event listener you have to call `infowindow.setContent()`. If you put in `bboxstr` you will get error because `map.getBounds()` returns object and `setContent()` expects a string. `infowindow` and `bboxstr` are completely separated variables. There is no any reference inside `infowindow` to `bboxstr`. So, for each change of `bboxstr` you have to call `setContent()` to change content string.

Comment: Anto is right. `bboxstr` is object. See my example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReneKorss/CL6cH/12/). You can see `center` and `bboxstr` variables in console (F12)

Comment: Thanks @AntoJurković and @ReneKorss. With you help and examples I was able to get my code working as intended! I ended using `infowindow.setContent()` to update the infowindow. I also found that I could use `bboxstr.toString()` to easily set it as the content of the infowindow.